# Matrix factorization based recommendation using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recommendation-engine, matrix-factorization

I am new to tensor Flow and exploring about recommendation system using tensorflow. I have verified few sample codes in in github and come across mostly the same like following as the follwing

https://github.com/songgc/TF-recomm/blob/master/svd_train_val.py

But the question is, how do I pick top recommendation for user U1 in the above code?

If there any sample code or approach, please share. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a little difficult! Basically, when `svd` returns, it closes the session, and the tensors lose their values (you still keep the graph). There are a few options:

1. Save the model to a file and restore it later;
2. Don't put the session in a `with tf.Session() as sess: ....` block, and instead return the session;
3. Do the user processing inside the `with ...` block

The worst option is option 3: you should train your model separately from using it. The best approach is to save your model and weights somewhere, then restore the session. However, you are still left with the question of how you use this session object once you have recovered it. To demonstrate just that part, I am going to solve this problem using option 3, assuming that you know how to restore a session.

```
def svd(train, test):
    samples_per_batch = len(train) // BATCH_SIZE

    iter_train = dataio.ShuffleIterator([train["user"],
                                     train["item"],
                                     train["rate"]],
                                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

    iter_test = dataio.OneEpochIterator([test["user"],
                                     test["item"],
                                     test["rate"]],
                                    batch_size=-1)

    user_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name="id_user")
    item_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name="id_item")
    rate_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])

    infer, regularizer = ops.inference_svd(user_batch, item_batch, user_num=USER_NUM, item_num=ITEM_NUM, dim=DIM,
                                       device=DEVICE)
    global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()
    _, train_op = ops.optimization(infer, regularizer, rate_batch, learning_rate=0.001, reg=0.05, device=DEVICE)

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir="/tmp/svd/log", graph=sess.graph)
        print("{} {} {} {}".format("epoch", "train_error", "val_error", "elapsed_time"))
        errors = deque(maxlen=samples_per_batch)
        start = time.time()
        for i in range(EPOCH_MAX * samples_per_batch):
            users, items, rates = next(iter_train)
            _, pred_batch = sess.run([train_op, infer], feed_dict={user_batch: users, item_batch: items, rate_batch: rates})
            pred_batch = clip(pred_batch)
            errors.append(np.power(pred_batch - rates, 2))
            if i % samples_per_batch == 0:
                train_err = np.sqrt(np.mean(errors))
                test_err2 = np.array([])
                for users, items, rates in iter_test:
                    pred_batch = sess.run(infer, feed_dict={user_batch: users,item_batch: items})
                    pred_batch = clip(pred_batch)
                    test_err2 = np.append(test_err2, np.power(pred_batch - rates, 2))
                end = time.time()
                test_err = np.sqrt(np.mean(test_err2))
                print("{:3d} {:f} {:f} {:f}(s)".format(i // samples_per_batch, train_err, test_err, end - start))
                train_err_summary = make_scalar_summary("training_error", train_err)
                test_err_summary = make_scalar_summary("test_error", test_err)
                summary_writer.add_summary(train_err_summary, i)
                summary_writer.add_summary(test_err_summary, i)
                start = end

        # Get the top rated movie for user #1 for every item in the set
        userNumber = 1
        user_prediction = sess.run(infer, feed_dict={user_batch: np.array([userNumber]), item_batch: np.array(range(ITEM_NUM))})
        # The index number is the same as the item number. Orders from lowest (least recommended)
        # to largeset
        index_rating_order = np.argsort(user_prediction)

        print "Top ten recommended items for user {} are".format(userNumber)
        print index_rating_order[-10:][::-1]  # at the end, reverse the list

        # If you want to include the score:
        items_to_choose = index_rating_order[-10:][::-1]
        for item, score in zip(items_to_choose, user_prediction[items_to_choose]):
            print "{}:  {}".format(item,score)
```

The only changes I made begin at the first commented line. To emphasize again, best practice would be to train in this function, but to actually make your predictions separately.

Comment: I have made a GitHub repository that shows how you can make a predictor. It is based on TF-recomm: 
https://github.com/kiwidamien/TensorFlowRec

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It helps